# Flink, what's the behavior of minBy or maxBy if multiple records meet the condition

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm newbie to Flink and I'm wondering what's the behavior of minBy (guess for the maxBy is the same) if there are multiple records that have the minimum value. I noticed that Flink will output only one record in this case, but which one? The first, the last or a random one?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that as of [FLIP-134](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/FLIP-134%3A+Batch+execution+for+the+DataStream+API#FLIP134:BatchexecutionfortheDataStreamAPI-DeprecatingRelationalmethodsonDataStream) all of these relational methods on DataStreams, namely `Windowed/KeyedStream#sum,min,max,minBy,maxBy`, are planned to be deprecated. The entire DataSet API is also planned to eventually be deprecated as well.

The only long-term support for relational methods like these is what is provided by the Table and SQL APIs.

But to answer your question, minBy and maxBy work the same way.

The javadoc for `DataSet#maxBy` says

> If multiple values with maximum value at the specified fields exist, a random one will be
> picked.

while the javadocs for `AllWindowedStream#maxBy(int positionToMaxBy)` and `KeyedStream#maxBy(int positionToMaxBy)` say

> If more elements have the same maximum value the operator returns the first by default.

and the javadocs for `AllWindowedStream#maxBy(int positionToMaxBy, boolean first)` and `AllWindowedStream#maxBy(int positionToMaxBy, boolean first)` explain that

> If [first is] true, then the operator return the first element with the maximum value,
> otherwise returns the last